# jQuery addClass working but javascript classList.add not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a class via javascript but it does not update in my DOM.
When I use jQuery though everything works as expected.
The issue is adding the svg--active class is not working.
item.classList.add('tab-brackground--active') works.

My jQuery code -

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const svg = document.querySelector('svg')

    if (svg) {
        const items = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item'
        )

        if (items) {
            items.forEach((item) => {
                item.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
                    item.classList.add('tab-brackground--active')
                    const text = e.target.children[0].innerText
                    jQuery(`[data-section="${text.toLowerCase()}"]`).addClass(
                        'svg--active'
                    )
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Same thing done with javascript that doesn't work -

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const svg = document.querySelector('svg')

    if (svg) {
        const items = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item'
        )

        if (items) {
            items.forEach((item) => {
                item.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
                    item.classList.add('tab-brackground--active')
                    const text = e.target.children[0].innerText
                    document.querySelector(`[data-section="${text.toLowerCase()}"]`).classList.add(
                        'svg--active'
                    )
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

When I console.log my javascript element it shows the element with the class added but when I go to check the DOM the class is not added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const svg = document.querySelector('svg')

    if (svg) {
        const items = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item'
        )

        if (items) {
            items.forEach((item) => {
                item.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
                    item.classList.add('tab-brackground--active')
                    const text = e.target.children[0].innerText
                    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-section="${text.toLowerCase()}"]`);
                    for(let i=0 ;i<nodeList.length; i++) {
                      nodeList[i].classList.add('svg--active')
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This worked! Do you have any idea why my original code didn't work tho?

Comment: Yes at your code you have been calling the querySelector instead of querySelectorAll. querySelector will take only the first match. querySelectorAll takes all the element that matches with the given selector.